# CDI beans without faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I want to use CDI beans into JSF application. I'm interested is there any possible way to avoid the bean declaration into faces-config.xml file. I want to use annotations to declare the beans similar to JSF beans. Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to declare CDI beans anywhere (except for the according annotation on the injection point). All you need is a `beans.xml` - it may as well be empty - either in the `META-INF` or in the `WEB-INF` folder of your war.

For web applications it is a common practice to put the `beans.xml` in the `WEB-INF` folder.

[**Here**](http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsBeansxmlAndWhyDoINeedIt) you can find a nice explanation of the technical background.